# Geth Plasma Shotgun charged damage?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The Geth Plasma Shotgun consumes 2 ammunition each charged shot. 
How much more damage does it deal compared to a normal shot?

Comment: This is probably testable in the Target Range unless it does too much damage per bullet

Comment: definitely too much damage per bullet

Comment: Yeah, a normal shot from the GPS kills any of the targets. :3

Answer (score 1):

I believe it does double damage. The idea behind the charged attack is for Corner-Rushing. You get ready to turn a corner on an enemy, and you charge the gun before you run in so you can finish them quickly without getting hurt so you can claim the cover in a firefight.

Answer (score 1):

Uncharged shots deal damage equal to 45% of a fully charged shot.
In other words charged shots deal 222.(2)% the damage of an uncharged shot.

Comment: This answer is correct, based on the spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhtHmyPMLnBadGowOTYzWXpua0VLT3d3Y1A4cGxQYnc#gid=1